# Sphinx 4: Same inputs produce different results each time

Tags: sphinx4

I want to make Sphinx4 deterministic. Each time I give the same input files in my unit tests, I want it to recognize the same words (with same timestamps). I've tried looking through the source code and fixing all calls to `new Random()`, but that doesn't seem to be enough. What am I missing? What other sources of randomness can there be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked with Sphinx devs. For one thing, it's important to use SimpleAcousticScorer instead of the ThreadedAcousticScorer. Also perhaps SimpleActiveListFactory instead of PartitionActiveListFactory. But even that was not enough. In short, we couldn't figure it out. But if I make headway, I'll post here.